# Working RouteService Function is Returning "Undefined" When Used in Another Component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am running two checks and then conditionally populating some data to certain routes if both conditions are met. In my room.component.html file I am using an *ngIf for this:

```
<div *ngIf="isLoggedIn() && isRoomRoute()" class="others">
  ... do some work
</div>
```

My room.component.ts file looks like this:

```
import { RouteService } from './../../data/route.service';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthenticationService } from './../../data/authentication.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-room',
  templateUrl: './room.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./room.component.less']
})
export class RoomComponent {

  model: any = {};
  loading = false;
  username;
  password;
  routeUrl;

  private url = 'http://localhost:5000';

  constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
              private router: Router,
              private routeService: RouteService,
              private appComponent: AppComponent) { }

  isLoggedIn() {
    this.loading = true;
    if (this.authenticationService.isAuthenticated()) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  isRoomRoute(routeUrl) {
    if (this.routeService.isRoomRoute(this.routeUrl)) {
      return true;
    }
  }

}
```

As you can see above, the second check is using a function from my routeService. That function looks like this:

```
  isRoomRoute(routeUrl) {
      if (routeUrl.includes('staff')) {
          console.log('This url: ' + routeUrl + ' is a roomRoute');
          return true;
      } else {
          console.log('This url: ' + routeUrl + ' is NOT a room route');
          return false;
      }
  }
```

This urls are being tracked in my app.component, which is using the routeService in the constructor, and looks like this:

```
constructor(private routeService: RouteService,
            private router: Router)
{
    this.router.events.subscribe((route) => {
    let routeUrl = route.url;
    this.routeService.sendRoute(routeUrl);
    this.routeService.isRoomRoute(routeUrl);
    });
}
```

I am successfully getting the right result from my routerService's "isRoomRoute" function, but I am getting an "undefined" error when I try and pass that result to my room component, even though I though I am calling the routeService in that component. So my question is, what am I missing that's making the result "undefined" from the room component? How do I pass a boolean value from the result of the isRoomRoute() function in the routeService to my room component?

Comment: i think you should write the else as well for this function                                      isRoomRoute(routeUrl) {
    if (this.routeService.isRoomRoute(this.routeUrl)) {
      return true;
    } else { return false } 
  }

Comment: or just do this in component   isRoomRoute(routeUrl) {
    return this.routeService.isRoomRoute(this.routeUrl)) 
  }

Comment: If you mean the function in the routeService file, it already does have an else statement:
  isRoomRoute(routeUrl) {
      if (routeUrl.includes('crew')) {
          console.log('This url: ' + routeUrl + ' is a roomRoute');
          return true;
      } else {
          console.log('This url: ' + routeUrl + ' is NOT a room route');
          return false;
      }
  }